# Replicate results from JSI using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, java

I am using OSM and facing an issue with finding the nearest road-segments to a given lat/lon point.

I have a code that uses Java Spatial Index [JSI](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/) which traverses the RTree index while computing the distance between the lat/lon point and the bounding rectangle of the objects using the [distance-function](https://github.com/aled/jsi/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/jsi/Rectangle.java#L217).

Now I am trying to implement the same functionality using PostGIS. After some reading I ended up with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT osm_id FROM planet_osm_line 
WHERE way <#> ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:plon, :plat), 4326), 900913) < :range
```

where `:range` is the max distance in meters.

My questions are

1. Is the use of the `<#>`? my understanding is that this function would calculate the distance to the edges of the BB, although I don't know how exactly.
2. Is the transformation to `900913` correct? Does this compute the distance between 2 geometries or geographies? I am confused with the relation between SRIDs and the use of geography in the computations of distances.
3. Does using the `<#>` in the `WHERE` clause utilize the index of the table? I found some references stating that the function will utilize the index only when used with `ORDER BY` clause.